# Где можно найти CMS?

Tags: cms

Интересуют меня не Wordpress, Joomla или другие популярные CMS, а более простые, бесплатные с открытым кодом. Возможно есть у кого-то на github или еще где-то. В первую очередь нужно для того чтобы понять как он построен з середины, набраться опыта так сказать. Благодарю за информацию!

Comment: Основная часть CMS написаны на PHP и если вас интересует вопрос именно создания своей CMS с нуля, то я бы не советовал копаться в этом говне мамонта. Лучше начните с поиска идеального языка для ваших задач, а не с примеров. Ну а если вы принципиально хотите написать CMS именно на PHP, то это пустая трата времени, поскольку в этой области уже существует огроменный велопарк.

Comment: Django cms, правда на python - довольно прозрачная. К слову wordpress для разбора - не сказал бы, что сложный. После джумлы очень понятный, с отличной длкументацией, правда, многое в процедурном стиле